# $ P: \mathbb{R} \to GL_n (\mathbb{C}) $ be an application of class $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then $ t \to P^{-1} (t) $ is of class $C ^1$

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, derivatives

Let $ P: \mathbb{R} \to GL_n (\mathbb{C}) $ be an application of class $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Why $Q: t \to P^{-1} (t) $ is of class $C ^1$

Answer (score 2):

Sketch: Let $M(P(t))$ be the matrix of $P(t).$ Then each entry in $M(P(t))$ is $C^1.$ Now $[P(t)]^{-1}$ has matrix

$$\tag 1 \frac{1}{\text{det } M(P(t))}\cdot C(t),$$

where $C(t)$ is the cofactor matrix of $M(P(t)).$ This implies all entries in the matrix $[P(t)]^{-1}$ are $C^1,$ which is the desired result.